# Cassandra read after write inconsistency with LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, consistency

We are running a cassandra cluster with a local data-center of 3 nodes and (I believe) a replication factor of 3.
A remote data-center exist, but isn't used in our queries.

We use Java libraries, more precisely :

- **org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all** coupled with **com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core both v3.1.1** for database interaction
- **info.archinnov:achilles-core v5.1.3** for code source annotation processing - this is where the **LOCAL_QUORUM** consistency level is specified

Recently, we've faced issues related to read after write consistency for new row insert.

A row is inserted using **LOCAL_QUORUM** consistency. Few milliseconds after the successful insert, the row select by partition key with **LOCAL_QUORUM** consistency is sometimes - rarely - unsuccessful. No row can be found.

**From my naive understanding of LOCAL_QUORUM consistency, if the row is written then read using LOCAL_QUORUM consistency (with same data-center), it should "always" be found and read.**
**But it isn't what seems to be happening.**

After reading the Cassandra documentation, I'm wondering if clock synchronization issues could explain the issue. Example : the node without the row could have a clock that is in advance and thus "no row" might be considered as the most updated value.

Is it indeed possible that node clock synchronization issues could explain read after write inconsistency for row insert (despite LOCAL_QUORUM and single local data center) ?
If not, what could explain such a consistency issue ?

Comment: Can you check replication factor for your keyspace?

Comment: perhaps make sure your executing queries with timestamps so you know the 2nd queries are later then first and make sure your clients clocks are in sync.

Comment: @Alex Ott replication factor is confirmed to equal 3

Comment: I meant - what replication strategy?

Answer (score 0):

can you execute below command to verify, how many node have the data for key.

```
./nodetool getendpoints keyspacename tablename 'keyname'
```